# elementos repetidos en un array

Tags: java, array, números-enteros

Tengo pasar de un array de int a otro solo los números pares. Solo se que esta guardando en los 10 espacios del código el mismo valor

```
int [] Numeros = {22, 36, 58, 78, 25, 47, 102, 55, 78, 12236, 1247, 77, 24};
    int [] Impares=new int [10];
    int [] Pares=new int [10];
    for (int i = 0; i < Numeros.length; i++) {
        if (Numeros[i]%2==0) {
            int k;
            for ( k = 0; k < Pares.length; k++) {
                Pares[k]=Numeros[i];
            }
        }else {
            for (int j = 0; j < Impares.length; j++) {
                Impares[j]=Numeros[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hace falta los bucles for, con ellos estas asignando a todas las posiciones de 0 a length el mismo valor. Puedes tener dos contadores que se vayan incrementando a medida que insertes un par o un impar, algo como:

```
int [] Numeros = {22, 36, 58, 78, 25, 47, 102, 55, 78, 12236, 1247, 77, 24};
int [] Impares= new int [10];
int [] Pares= new int [10];

int k = 0;
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Numeros.length; i++) {
  if (Numeros[i]%2==0) {
    Pares[k]=Numeros[i];
    k = k + 1;
  }
  else {
    Impares[j]=Numeros[i];
    j = j + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Y si por casualidad todos los números del arreglo son pares, creo q mejor seria usar listas y así no se desperdicia espacio